# How to display a dynamic array with a for loop in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, for-loop, dynamic

I am trying to display a dynamic array to check my inputs using a for loop and without any vector (I'm still a beginner so I don't know what it means yet and it's a class assignment). I am also trying to implement classes and objects. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Set {
private:
    int size;
    int* arr = new int[size];
public:
    void setArr();
    void dispArr();
};

void Set::setArr() {
    cout << "Please enter the size of your array: ";
    cin >> size;

    cout << "\nPlease enter the elements of your array: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cin >> arr[i];
}

void Set::dispArr() {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        cout << arr[j] << "\t";
}

void main()
{
    Set myArray;

    myArray.setArr();

    myArray.dispArr();
}
```

When I run the code, sometimes it works, but most of the time, it throws a breakpoint error without any error code or explanation. Could someone help me figure out how to combine dynamic arrays and classes?
Please and thank you.

Comment: Don't use `int* arr = new int[size];` when you declare arr - just use `int* arr;` and then in `setArr` put `arr = new int[size];` after `cin >> size;` so that size has a have before you create the array.

Comment: An aside: If you are going to make classes that directly contain dynamically allocated memory, you owe it to yourself to be familiar with [The Rule of Three (and friends)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: `int* arr = new int[size];` means that `arr` should be initialized to `new int[size]` when an instance of `Set` is created. The value of `size` is evaluated, and `arr` points to an array of that size, whatever value `size` had at the time the array was created. Changing `size` later does not resize the array. No relationship is created between `arr` and `size` and changing `size` has no effect on `arr`. Since `size` is uninitialized when `new int[size]` is evaluated, its value is indeterminate and any attempt to use that value has Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allocating `arr` before you initialise `size`.  As a result, `size` has an indeterminate value at that point which explains your program's unpredicatable behaviour.

Solution: allocate `arr` *after* reading `size`.  Better yet, use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).